# Is there a way to recreate the typical Red/Blue-Postereffect using Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing, generative-art

I think nearly all of us have at least once seen an image like this:

[image]

So I wondered whether it is possible to recreate this effect using Mathematica because it seems like it wouldn't need that many processing steps.

Any ideas?

http://hplussummit.com/images/wolfram.jpg this can be used as a source image.

Comment: "because it seems like it wouldn't need that many processing steps." Not true in the case of the Barack Obama poster: http://www.dvxuser.com/V6/showthread.php?157753-How-to-Recreate-Barack-Obama-Posters

Comment: http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-inspirational-vector-political-poster--vector-17 as well

Comment: Did you try anything? `ColorReplace` and `Colorize` should be useful here.

Comment: Well, it might be possible, I was about to give it a go...

Comment: I don't think you should delete the question. There are no close votes, either. But most image processing questions at least contain some `img = Import[url of a good source image]` code snippet, so everyone can start playing around right away, and the resulting answers are comparable.

Comment: `Colorize[image, ColorFunction -> cfunc]` is probably what you want, although coming up with the appropriate `cfunc` is the trick.

Comment: @acl `ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{Darker@Blue, # < 0.5}, {Red, # < 0.67}, {Darker@LightBlue, # < 0.75}, {LightYellow, True}}] &)`

Comment: All the answers are quite fine. I upVoted all of them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's my attempt, using @RahulNarain `ColorFunction` with different colors:

```
obamaize[image_, text_] := 
 Module[{colored = 
  Colorize[image, 
   ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{RGBColor[{30, 60, 88}/255], # < 0.5},
   {RGBColor[{202,36, 40}/255], # < 0.67}, {RGBColor[{124, 151, 168}/255], # < 0.75}, 
   {RGBColor[{240, 232, 173}/255], True}}] &)], 
   dims = ImageDimensions[image]},
  ImagePad[
   ImageAssemble[{{colored}, {Rasterize[
   Style[text, 40, FontFamily -> "Arial Black", Bold, 
    RGBColor[{124, 151, 168}/255]], ImageSize -> dims[[2]], 
   Background -> RGBColor[{30, 60, 88}/255]]}}], 10, 
 RGBColor[{240, 232, 173}/255]]
]
```

And to test it:

```
obamaize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "LENA"]
```

[image]

```
obamaize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Girl2"}], "ARRGH"]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - but why obama? he isn't that red, is he?

Comment: +1!!! Add a bit of filtering to remove the noisy pixels? `Colorize[GaussianFilter[image, 1.5]...`, or a bilateral filter

Comment: @eldo - this is why http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama_%22Hope%22_poster, this is the inspiration for this type of image

Comment: @blochwave, kale: I find that running `Colorize` on `TotalVariationFilter@Sharpen@image` works pretty well.

Comment: Yeah I was about to suggest TV - `PeronaMalikFilter` is another possibility http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeronaMalikFilter.html

Comment: @RahulNarain Edit as you see fit.

Answer (score 23):

A somewhat revised approach.

First define the colours and create column images from them. There are four block colours and one striped.

```
blue = {0.15, 0.23, 0.33};
red = {0.77, 0.16, 0.17};
paleblue = {0.50, 0.60, 0.63};
beige = {0.96, 0.90, 0.69};

cols = Image[Table[Transpose[{##}], {60}] ~Flatten~ 1] & /@
   {{blue}, {red}, {paleblue}, {paleblue, beige}, {beige}};
```

Now import the image and do some processing. I repeatedly apply a low pass transform and histogram equalisation, then afterwards do a quantisation. The aim is to split the image into 5 brightness regions which have reasonably smooth outlines and which are all about the same area (so that the final image contains all five colours in equal amounts).

```
i1 = Import["wolfram.jpg"] ~ColorConvert~ "Grayscale";
id = ImageDimensions[i1];

i2 = Nest[HistogramTransform@LowpassFilter[#, 1.5] &, i1, 10];
i3 = ImageApply[0.2 Floor[5 #] &, i2];

{i1, i2, i3} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Now I use `Binarize` to extract masks for the individual regions and create shader images from the colours.

```
masks = Table[Binarize[i3, {i, 1.01 i}], {i, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2}];

shaders = ImageResize[#, id] & /@ cols;

{masks, shaders} // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

Finally combine the mask and shader images, and add a label and border:

```
i4 = Inner[ImageMultiply, masks, shaders, ImageAdd];

label = Rasterize[
   Style["WOLFRAM", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, RGBColor@paleblue],
   ImageSize -> id[[1]], Background -> RGBColor@blue];

ImagePad[ImageAssemble[{{i4}, {label}}], 10, RGBColor@red]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you got the colors reversed for the text & bg... great answer nevertheless! Now if only there was a way to fix that hatch from bleeding into the bg... :)

Comment: @rm-rf, oh - so I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

First off, here's @kale's excellent answer modified with a bilateral filter to smooth it a little:

```
kalesObamaize[image_, text_] := 
 Module[{colored = 
    Colorize[BilateralFilter[image, 2, 0.5], 
     ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{RGBColor[{30, 60, 88}/255], # < 
            0.5}, {RGBColor[{202, 36, 40}/255], # < 
            0.67}, {RGBColor[{124, 151, 168}/255], # < 
            0.75}, {LightYellow, True}}] &)], 
   dims = ImageDimensions[image]}, 
  ImagePad[ImageAssemble[{{colored}, {Rasterize[
       Style[text, 40, FontFamily -> "Arial Black", Bold, 
        RGBColor[{124, 151, 168}/255]], ImageSize -> dims[[2]], 
       Background -> RGBColor[{30, 60, 88}/255]]}}], 10, 
   RGBColor[0.94, 0.91, 0.68]]]
kalesObamaize[Import[
  "http://hplussummit.com/images/wolfram.jpg"], "WOLVERINE"]
```

[image]

---

Second, here's my attempt. The motivation for this is based more on the workflow used in e.g. Adobe Illustrator to vectorize the image, which is how the original example would have been done.

I've not played around with the colours that much (to match the question) so it can definitely be improved. Call it a work-in-progress, suggestions welcome!

Also, if anyone can help me tidy up the code that separates the image out into layers that would be great!

```
wolfram = 
  ImageAdjust[Import["http://hplussummit.com/images/wolfram.jpg"]];
(* it's this line I'm not sure about! *)
binlist = 
  Reverse[Transpose[{Range[0., 0.8, 0.2], Range[0.2, 1.0, 0.2]}]];
binarylist = MorphologicalBinarize[wolfram, #] & /@ binlist;
imglist = GaussianFilter[#, 1.5] & /@ binarylist
```

[image]

```
combinedimages = ImageAdjust[Fold[ImageAdd,
   ColorReplace[imglist[[5]], {Black -> Darker@LightBlue}],
   {
    ColorReplace[imglist[[4]], {Black -> Red}],
    ColorReplace[imglist[[3]], {Black -> Red}],
    ColorReplace[imglist[[2]], {Black -> Darker@Blue}]
    }]]
```

[image]

```
ImageMultiply[
 Colorize[imglist[[1]], 
  ColorRules -> {Black -> LightYellow}], combinedimages]
```

[image]

Comment: One of the things is getting the colours to be vibrant - adding like this with `ImageAdd` needs transparency in the layers instead of white areas.

Answer (score 8):

Here a different approach, that mainly uses the build in `ImageEffect` `"Posterization"` and `ColorReplace`:
First the image is imported, the background removed and blured a bit:

```
img1=Blur@*RemoveBackground@Import["http://hplussummit.com/images/wolfram.jpg"];
```

Than the `ImageEffect` is applied:

```
img2=ImageEffect[img1,{"Posterization",2}];
```

The dominant colors are determined with

```
dColors=DominantColors[img2,4];
```

and will be replaced using the following rules:

```
colorReplaceRules={dColors[[1]]->RGBColor[{124,151,168}/255],dColors[[2]]->RGBColor[{240,232,173}/255],dColors[[3]]->RGBColor[{202,36,40}/255],dColors[[4]]->RGBColor[{30,60,88}/255]}
```

Now the colors can be replaced using

```
img3 = ColorReplace[img2, colorReplaceRules, 0.001];
```

With a new background created by

```
newBackground=With[{imgDim=ImageDimensions@img1},
 Image@Graphics[{RGBColor[{202,36,40}/255],Rectangle[{0,0},{Round[1/2*imgDim[[1]]],imgDim[[2]]}],RGBColor[{124,151,168}/255],Rectangle[{Round[1/2*imgDim[[1]]],0},{imgDim[[1]],imgDim[[2]]}]},Background->None,Frame->False,PlotRangePadding->None,ImagePadding->None,ImageSize->imgDim]];
```

the final image can be composed

```
ImageCompose[newBackground, img3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here one approach:

```
im=Import["http://hplussummit.com/images/wolfram.jpg"];
mb=MorphologicalBinarize[im];
cb=ChanVeseBinarize[im];
ia1=ImageAdd[ColorReplace[im,ColorNegate[mb]->Darker@Blue],mb];
ia2=ImageAdd[ColorReplace[RemoveBackground[im],ColorNegate[cb]->Darker@Red],cb];
new1=ImageCompose[ImageCompose[Image@Graphics[{Darker@Blue,Rectangle[{0,0},{120,240}],Darker@Red,Rectangle[{120,0},{240,240}]},Background->None,Frame->False,PlotRangePadding->None,ImagePadding->None,ImageSize->240],ColorReplace[ia2,Binarize[ia2]->Orange]],
RemoveBackground[ia1]];
```

And a simple cleanup

```
ColorReplace[new1,Binarize[new1,0.95]->Darker@Blue]
```

Results in:
[image]
Some hair is still left without proper coloring, but more carefull adjustments of threshold values (here mainly default values were used) should solve this.

Answer (score 5):

This is a followup to @Simon Woods' answer and @rm -rf's comment

> Now if only there was a way to fix that hatch from bleeding into the bg...

There is!

Let's create a face mask:

```
i = Import["wolfram.jpg"];
face = FindFaces[i][[1]];
facemask = 
 Graphics[{White, 
   Circle[Mean[face], (Mean[face] - face[[1]])*{.8, 1.2}]},
  Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[i], 
  PlotRange -> {0, #} & /@ Reverse[ImageDimensions[i]], 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]]
```

Now we only need to modify the existing masks:

```
cutoff = DeleteSmallComponents[
   ImageSubtract[masks[[4]], ChanVeseBinarize[i, facemask]], 50];
masks[[4]] = ImageSubtract[masks[[4]], cutoff];
masks[[3]] = ImageAdd[masks[[3]], cutoff];
```

And produce the poster without the bleeding hatch in the background:

```
i4 = Inner[ImageMultiply, masks, shaders, ImageAdd];

label = Rasterize[
   Style["WOLFRAM", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 
    RGBColor@paleblue], ImageSize -> id[[1]], 
   Background -> RGBColor@blue];

ImagePad[ImageAssemble[{{i4}, {label}}], 10, RGBColor@red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, I can't figure out why setting the `Background` color of the label does not work for me.

---

And here is an alternative approach, thanks to @Pickett:

```
i = Import["wolfram.jpg"];
bg = Binarize[RemoveBackground@i, 0.01];
colorbg = 
  Graphics[{RGBColor@paleblue, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {0, 1}], 
    RGBColor@red, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {1, 1}]}, 
   Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[i]];
i5 = ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[i4, bg], 
  ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@bg, colorbg]]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried my hands on this as well using MMA10's `RemoveBackground`. My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/bsYgS3W8) and it yields [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/80pmH.png) result. You can add it as another alternative for fixing the problem if you like if you'd like.

Comment: @Pickett thanks, added

Answer (score 4):

Using Rahul's idea and a bit of blurring:

```
img = Import["http://hplussummit.com/images/wolfram.jpg"];

bimg = Blur[img];
Colorize[
 bimg, ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{Darker@Blue, # < 0.5}, {Red, # < 
        0.67}, {Darker@LightBlue, # < 0.75}, {LightYellow, True}}] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, very short, but the `Blue` is far too aggresive, and the `Red` could be a nuance darker.

Comment: complaints should be addressed to @RahulNarain who came up with the colours. I'm just here to collect the votes :)

Comment: @eldo the comment above was for you

Comment: Half the reason I didn't post an answer was so that I wouldn't have to bother making the colours look good! So please, do direct any and all complaints towards @acl. Indeed, that blue is terrible, acl, what on earth were you thinking?!

Comment: @RahulNarain truth be told, I did try improving them and got bored after 20s. So I understand you (but I'll hold on to those sweet upvotes anyway)